# Sum of Square Between Groups for dataframe

Tags: python

```
variable   value

G1           1 
G1           2
G2           3
G2           4
G3           5
G3           6
```

How can I calculate sum of squared between groups ? For example;

SSB = ((G1)**2/n +(G2)**2/n + (G3)**2/n) - (21)**2/6

Comment: Please add the data sample directly to your question body as text, not as a picture. Also, show us what you have tried so far, and why your attempt isn't giving you the result that you expect. See: [Research Effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Finally, add the expected result.

Comment: I've edited yet but can't anything for sum of squred between groups. I just want to help

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting your formula as wanting the following:

```
SSB = (
  sum(G1)**2/len(G1) +
  sum(G2)**2/len(G2) + 
  sum(G3)**2/len(G3) +
  ...
) - sum(Gall)**2/len(Gall)
```

I assume `df` is your DataFrame:

```py
Gn = df.groupby('variable').value.agg(['sum', 'size'])
Gall = df.value.agg(['sum', 'size'])
SSB = (Gn['sum']**2/Gn['size']).sum() - Gall['sum']**2/Gall['size']
```

If I understand correctly, then `SSB` should contain the result you are interested in.

Comment: Tobias thanks but your code is calculating different thing.  I want like this: Firstly, Calculate sum of G1 Values and take square then divide 'n'. after that do same thing for G2,G3 and substract from sum(allvalues)**2/N

Comment: Could you update your question with what you want the output to look like for the input in your example?